# How to get only the first value using map method over an array of object

Tags: javascript

What I need is only the `apple` from objects inside an array.

```
const fruits = [{name: "apple"}, {name: "banana"}]

fruits.map((f)=>{
  console.log(f.name[0])
})
```

Comment: You don't want to use `.filter` or `.find` ???

Comment: You mean like `fruits[0].name` to get the `name` of the first object?

Comment: `fruits.find(x => x.name === "apple")`

Comment: or you mean `fruits.map(f=>console.log(f.name))`... you don't need the `[0]`

Comment: `fruits.map(f=>console.log(f.name)) ` gives a list of apple and banana. What I need is just apple alone.

Comment: Yeah then use `fruits.filter(x=>x.name==="apple")` (all results) or `.find` (first result)

Comment: @Arne `fruits[0].name` repeats apple twice in the console.

Comment: Cody. lets assume that we don't know the first value of the object. How do I get the first object's value? it doesn't matter if it is an apple or something else.

Comment: @Deke about twice in the console, that's because you are using it inside the map function You don't need a map function to get the first, use it directly: `fruits[0].name`

Comment: from lodash I like `_.get(fruits,'[0]','yourdefaultvalue')` but in this case I would just use `fruits.length > 0 ? fruits[0].name ? fruits[0].name : '' : ''` .... idk why you need map

Comment: Never use `map` to `console.log` something because it allocates a new array and is semantically confusing. `forEach` is appropriate. As others have mentioned, if you want a single item, just use `fruits[0]`, skip the `map` entirely. If, for some reason, you need to keep the map and just get one or a few items, prepend `slice`: `fruits.slice(0, 1).map(e => /* this callback is only applied to the first element */)` but that's a pretty silly pattern -- the question in general seems to be coming from a state of confusion, probably an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `map` functions receives a second argument that is the interator value. So, that code will work:

```js
const fruits = [{name: "apple"}, {name: "banana"}]
fruits.map((f, i)=>{
  if (i === 0) {
    console.log(f.name);
  }
});
```

But, I guess that a `forEach` is more appropriate, because `map` is normally used to convert a array to another array and a forEach is used to make loops.

```js
const fruits = [{name: "apple"}, {name: "banana"}];
fruits.forEach((f, i)=>{
  if (i === 0) {
    console.log(f.name);
  }
});
```

If you want to know what is inside the first element of the array, you can do that without using loops. You can access it directly:

```js
const fruits = [{name: "apple"}, {name: "banana"}];    
const first = fruits[0];
console.log(first.name);
```

Comment: your first answer using map is what I'm looking for. map only the first value into another array

Comment: In that case you should be using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), @Deke.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't make much sense, but this works:

```js
const fruits = [{name: "apple"}, {name: "banana"}]
var i = 0;
fruits.map((f)=>{
  if (i == 0) {
    console.log(f.name);
  }
  i++;
})
```

Comment: ( ಠ_ಠ) ... This answer just needs a little more pizzazz